# change primary key with linq in c#

Tags: c#, linq

How can I change primary key with linq in c# 
I try

```
db.SubmitChange();
```

an error occur.
Then I realized linq does not allow to change primary key field in my c# program
How can I fix this problem.

Comment: You need to drop the row and add it back again, this time with new PK.

Comment: Why do you want to change a primary key?

Comment: I think you cant change primarykey with linq. You need to do it on database.

Answer (score 2):

You can't update a primary key using LINQ. You need to delete that row from the database and add a new one with the new primary key. You can do that in the database **using SQL** but it should be **Unique** and **shouldn't violate any foreign key constraint**.